# Missing permalink for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have created the CPT, when I add a new post to the CPT the permalink is empty,

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have added the picture where I'm getting and stuck up and I'm new to the WordPress.

Kindly, can anyone help me to resolve this issues, I have changed the permalinks and lot more what I have received from Google but can't find the solution.

Urgent

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the option "Rewrite" set to True. It should solve the problem.

Comment: If this weren't set then the permalink would just be the plain type, not missing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue when registering the custom post type via template code. That's why "the_permalink" and the "get_permalink" functions were also returning "null" within the post loop of the custom post type archive page.

I didn't find the reason or a code wise fix but **after installing the ["Permalink Manager" Plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/) it was fairly easy to work around the issue**. I just needed to adjust my permalink structure in the settings and regenerate all links of my CPT.